# populate Listview with array of strings

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-template

I have created a jsbin at http://jsbin.com/ifimadOw/11/edit to illustrate.

I have this listview object:

```
<ul id="marketplace-categories-listview" data-bind="source: results"></ul>
```

And I have this dataset:

```
dsCats = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: myUrl,
            data: {
                key: myKey
            }
        }
    }
});

$("#marketplace-categories-listview").kendoMobileListView({
    dataSource: dsCats,
    template: $("#marketplace-product-template").text()
});
```

The data returned from the API looks something like this:

```
{"count": 3, "results": ["Acupuncture Therapy","Automobiles","Lawn Care"]}
```

And here is my template:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="marketplace-categories-template">
    <li data-bind="text: this"></li>
</script>
```

Because my data doesn't have named elements, I can't use something like "#:category#" in the template.  I have also tried data-bind (as above), but so far nothing works.  Surely there is a way to do this.

Comment: Isn't the <li></li> tag implied ? Try changing the <li ...></li> to <span ...></span>

Comment: using <span> threw the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'slice'"

Comment: I'm curious about the schema.data.key : myKey.  What is that for ?

Comment: Thats a key the the API needs.  It gets converted to a URL parameter.

Comment: I have created a jsbin at http://jsbin.com/ifimadOw/11/edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use `data` (which is the name of the context variable passed to the template function) in your template:

```
  $("#category-listview").kendoMobileListView({
    dataSource: dsCats,
    template: "#= data #"
  });
```

(updated [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/obeWimI/5/edit))

Comment: Aha! Nailed it.  Thank you so much -- I have spent way too much time looking for a solution for this.  FYI, using <li> in the template caused duplicated <li> rows so I used <span> instead and got what I was looking for.

Comment: yeah, that was a mistake since the `<li>` elements are created by the widget itself; fixed